# Why is default layout not being applied to pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to use Github Pages and Jekyll for the first time. I created a repo and followed the instructions to set it up.

I am having trouble getting the default layout to work. A layout file: _layouts/default.html exists in the repository and my _config.yml looks like:

```yaml
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ''
    values:
      layout: 'default'
```

Even with the setting above, the pages are not getting the default layout applied. See the [Github Repositry](https://github.com/mb-dev/mb-dev.github.io) and [My github page](http://mb-dev.github.io/) that currently shows:

```
Look in _config.yml, why is default layout not being applied??
```

Without any layout.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All your pages** must have a front matter (event empty) if you want Jekyll to parse them.
Without a front matter, your pages are just copied like static files.

So, your index.html must be :

```
---
---
Look in _config.yml, why is default layout not being applied ?
```

default layout is them applied.